# Flutter Camera: sending app to background by home button throws exceptions

Tags: android, flutter, camera

I made a simple camera page by following the [tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera) from the Flutter website and it works fine under normal circumstances, but as I press the home button and the app is sent to background, this exception keeps being thrown continuously forever:

```
W/MessageQueue(18874): Handler (android.os.Handler) {da4ca60} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(18874): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {da4ca60} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:558)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:754)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:703)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:673)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:403)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraHandlerExecutor.execute(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2445)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onCaptureStarted(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2082)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceCallbacks$Stub.onTransact(ICameraDeviceCallbacks.java:158)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
W/MessageQueue(18874):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

(Dependency: camera: ^0.9.2+2)

Returning to the app does not stop the exceptions. Opening the Android camera app stops the exceptions but then my app's CameraPreview freezes when I return to it.

I have tried pausePreview() and resumePreview() but the exceptions start being thrown again after resuming.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is exactly like the one in tutorial, and I believe this problem is caused by lack of some code, not the code being wrong